# in C how can i store strings in a multidimensional table?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, store

I am trying to create a program for school where you can  register and login using your `name`, `surname`, `age` etc.

You can register up to 100 times using only different surnames each time.
I created the Register/login screen as follows

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    MSCREEN: printf ("              =====   Main Screen    =====                \n");
    printf ("To Register type: Register\n");
    printf ("To Log-In type: Login\n");
    char rl[9]; //rl=RegisterLogin
    while ((strcmp (rl, "Register") != 0) || (strcmp (rl, "register") != 0) || (strcmp (rl, "Login") != 0) || (strcmp (rl, "login") != 0)) {
        scanf (" %s", &rl);
        if((strcmp(rl,"Register")==0) || (strcmp(rl,"register")==0)) {
            printf ("You will now Register\n");
            Register();
            i++;
            goto MSCREEN;
            break;
        }
        else if ((strcmp(rl,"Login")==0) || (strcmp(rl,"login")==0)) { 
            printf ("You will now Login");
            Login();
            break;
        }
        else{ 
        printf("Please type 'Register' or 'Login'\n"); 
        }
    }
    printf ("Completed");
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is that I don't exactly know how I can store the different names and surnames using multidimensional arrays. I cant use separate files or data structures for this so I'm stuck.

I need to be able to display the information in a 2 dimensional array but in order to store information I probably need a 3 dimensional array for this.
I also need to be able to edit the names using a separate function now something like this:

```
void Register()
{
    //char name[50], surname[50], age[50], lamia[50], patra[50], volos[50], sum[50];
    printf ("               =====   Register    =====               \n");
    
    printf ("Please type your Name:\n");
    scanf (" &s", &name[50]);
    
    printf ("Please type your Surname:\n");
    scanf (" &s", &surname[50]);
    
    printf ("Please type your Age:\n");
    scanf (" &s", &age[50]);
    
    printf ("Please type your Trips  to Lamia:\n");
    scanf (" &s", &lamia[50]);

    printf ("Please type your Trips  to Patra:\n");
    scanf (" &s", &patra[50]);

    printf ("Please type your Trips  to Volos:\n");
    scanf (" &s", &volos[50]);
    
    return;
```

will save the necessary info only as global variables which will change after the next registration.

So how can I store all the info I need on a multi-dimensional array and then be able to access that info later down the line?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to look into an array of structs. A single struct contains all information for a student, including a pointer to an array of names (if you haven't learned about memory allocation or pointers, there's no time like the present...). As an aside, it's very easy to smash the buffer in this code.

Comment: You can use a 3D array or an array of structs with the struct containing  one array for the name and one for the surname.

Comment: I am familiar with pointers and definitely confused by them so I am studying at the moment and clearing things up.. but using struct is pretty much frohibited for this one.. since its something the professor has not taught us yet in class, that would result on an F right away! (I used atoi and some other "untaught" knowledge and bamboozled myself last time..) thank you for answering. ill look into struct anyway (although I doubt Ill be able to solve this without using it) @ggorlen

Comment: @Davide Thats right .. a 3D Array was also my original thought and it fits with the knowledge im suppose to have but how can i store it in a 3D array to begin with? And after that how can I then edit those stings? When the user logs in, how can i authenticate the information... meaning...how can i access that info later? Im confused about the 3D array thing although i have no doubt that this is the way to go here

Comment: That's an unfortunate restriction because structs are the correct way to group different types of data together to represent an entity. It's too bad they're asking you to do a task that can be solved elegantly with a particular tool while prohibiting that tool. But in this case, since all your fields appear to be strings, you can use a `char[x][y][z];` where the first dimension is a list of students, the second dimension is essentially the flattened "struct" as an array and the third dimension are any lists that would be contained within this struct.

Comment: You could also use separate arrays, both 2d, one to store the flattened structs without the list field and the other to store the single field that has a list of values per student. This would be better for memory footprint, if that matters, but it's a bit harder to manage because you have to keep indices straight between two data structures. Both solutions make it much harder than this need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since you can't use structs, here's how you can use a 3D array

```
char students[STUD][DATA][LENGTH];
```

where `STUD` is the maximum number of students you want to store;
`DATA` is the number of entries for each student, in your case it's `2` (name and surname);
`LENGTH` is the maximum number of characters for each name/surname.

Every time you want to access the name of the n-th student you will refer to

```
students[n][0]
```

while for the surname you'd use

```
students[n][1]
```

`students[x]` represents a student and is a pointer to pointers to char (it points to the two pointers *name* and *surname*).

`student[x][y]` represents the name or surname of a student and is a pointer to char.

`student[x][y][z]` represents one of the characters composing the name or the surname.

If you want to print the data at some point in your program, I advise you to put a `'\0'` at the end of every name/surname while you fill them in the array.
And you should also keep track of the number of students you have initialized.

If you are not going to overwrite the students' data, you could even use `memset` to initialize every element with `'\0'` and then fill the data without caring about terminating your strings or keeping track of how many students you got.

Have fun.